# Htaccess rewriterule fix stylesheet

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, styles

My folder structure:

```
/root
  - blog.php
  - .htaccess
  /management
    /templates
      /template
        -style.css
        -image.png
        -javascript.js
```

My htaccess:

```
RewirteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog.update/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^blog.update/(.*)/(.*)$ /blog.php?ID=$1&title=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg|png|css|js|jpeg)$
RewriteRule .....
```

I'd like my image, styleshee and js files to be loaded in the blog.php file when i call them.
For instance:

```
<img src="management/templates/template/image.png" />
```

What should my latest RewriteRule contain to make this work?

Yes.. i did google this

No... i could not make it work

EDIT:
In the end the link should be like: 
blog.update/1/some_title_or_something

Comment: The src should be `/management/templates/...`

Comment: That is the <base href... solution, i'd like to have the rewriterule solution...

Comment: "to be loaded in the blog.php" what do you mean?

Comment: like when i'm on the page blog.update/1/this_is_my_blog_title i'd like the images, and stylesheets and javascripts to be 'loaded' / shown / used..... whatever you'd like to call it

Comment: Ok, I understand, The best way to do that is using the full path of the files, Or you can use the base metatag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: Yeah that's one way.. but isn't there a way using htaccess?

Comment: but I advise you don't use this metatag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120916/discussion-between-mart-haarman-and-mostafa).